# AWS Maximum BadRequestException retries reached for query Using Data API to Query RDS Serveless Aurora

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-aurora-serverless, aws-data-wrangler

I have created a Lambda function that uses awswrangler data api to read in data from an RDS Serverless Aurora PostgreSQL Database from a query. The query contains a conditional that is a list of IDs. If the query has less then 1K ids it works great, if over 1K I get this message:

`Maximum BadRequestException retries reached for query`

An example query is:

```
"""select * from serverlessDB where column_name in %s""" % ids_list
```

I adjusted the serverless RDS instance to force scaling as well as increased the concurrency on the lambda function. Is there a way fix this issue?

Comment: Is this the MySQL or PostgreSQL version of Serverless Aurora? Are you certain about the 1000 items threshold? e.g. 999 works but 1000+ doesn't?

Comment: @NoelLlevares PostgreSQL (I will edit the question)and my tests actually contained 980 ids and 1150 ids.

Answer (score 0):

With PostgreSQL, 1000+ items in a `WHERE IN` clause should be just fine.

I believe you are running into a Data API limit.

> There isn't a fixed upper limit on the number of parameter sets. However, the maximum size of the HTTP request submitted through the Data API is 4 MiB. If the request exceeds this limit, the Data API returns an error and doesn't process the request. This 4 MiB limit includes the size of the HTTP headers and the JSON notation in the request. Thus, the number of parameter sets that you can include depends on a combination of factors, such as the size of the SQL statement and the size of each parameter set.

> The response size limit is 1 MiB. If the call returns more than 1 MiB of response data, the call is terminated.

> The maximum number of requests per second is 1,000./

Either your request exceeds 4 MB or the response of your query exceeds 1 MB. I suggest you split your query into multiple smaller queries.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out in the docs Noel. I will need to set up a test to know the true size of the request/response but given the error I am definitely exceeding it. My other option would be to not go serverless. To be clear though, this is an aurora serverless issue and not a aws wrangler issue correct?